# Problem with showing errors with ActionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, ajax

Disclaimer : This is an homework exercise. Sort of. I'm trying to learn Visualforce + APEX + web design in a very short term, so I'm asking my friends to put up challenging questions for me.

[VF page](http://codepad.org/jtklB6Dc)

[Controller](http://codepad.org/3GmK2vEU)

**My aim :** show an alert/message when the user presses a button. Using ActionFunction. I must use Action Function

**Problems I am facing :**

1. Please look at my code [VF page](http://codepad.org/jtklB6Dc). I have marked the problem with a comment.
2. I donot know enough about AJAX/JS to fulfill all requirements.
3. The code is behaving weird.
4. I can display the alert/message without Action Function, I dont know how WITH AF.
5. The page refreshes after I click the button. Does a command button ALWAYS refresh after you click it?

I will expand on problem **1** :

If I remove the offending line, the code does not work. I click the button and page refreshes. NOTHING happens.

If I keep the offending line, when I click the button, it displays a JS alert and a few seconds later, it displays the Salesforce type error/message. **WHY??**

Is it possible to call a JS function from the controller?

My logic is like this :

1. Click the button.
2. It calls a JS function
3. the JS function calls the function related to the Action Function, and THAT in turn calls the controller function associated with the AF.
4. the controller calls back/returns value/changes a getter/setter to some value.
5. the value is taken by some other JS function defined in the page and it triggers a condition check (I'm pulling words out of my @$$ here) and THAT displays and alert.
6. phew

I hope this is not asking for the impossible??

I donot ask you folks to provide me a full detailed answer, just a few nudges in the right direction would be enough!! I dont need much hand holding.

Sorry for the wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="exampleCon">
    <script>    
function mtdOne(){  




alert('m inside javascript');

    controllermtd();

    }


    </script>
    <apex:form id="frm">


    <apex:outputText value="Clicked" id="showstate" rendered="{!flag}"/>


   <apex:commandButton value="Hit Me" onclick="mtdOne();return false;" />


    <apex:actionFunction action="{!sayhello}" name="controllermtd" rerender="frm">

    </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Below is the controller:

```
/*** Controller ***/
public class exampleCon {

    public boolean flag{get;set;}
    public static integer i=1;

    public examplecon(){


    flag=false;
    }



    public PageReference sayHello() {


        flag=true;



        return null;
    }



}
```

Hope this helps you(I am rerendering outputtext using actionfunction in my example)

Comment: If this helps you, mark this as the solution

Comment: This IS the answer! Im sorry Im late, I couldnt get to a PC on the weekend. You're a wizard... but can you please explain whats happening in the commandbutton onlick part? Thanks!

Comment: in the onClick(), we basically call up the javascript method.Inside that javascript method, i am calling the controller method by referring its name.We can also pass parameters using <apex:param>

Please refer to salesforce documentation for more understanding :)